Physics simulation changes on adding or rotating an object
So I am trying to make a marble run animation using physics like that in the videos of Victor De Martin. But after about going for about 100-200 frames, when i add a new platform for the marble, the trajectory of the marble changes from the previous frames. It happens even when I rotate an already added platform. So I have to adjust the previous frames but again after some frames the trajectory changes. Can you help with the problem?

It would be helpful if you could share the file. We have no idea how you add a new platform and how you set up your scene.
